# Exception xml.getElementsByTagName is not a function, when trying to parse an xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse xml from an notes.xml, it show an error in firebug as

```
    TypeError: xml.getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

My code part is,

notes.xml

```
    <fr>
    <franchise city="Scottsdale"  state=" AZ" />
    <franchise city="Arcadia" state=" CA" />
    </fr>
```

javascript

```
       <script>                      
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","notes.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("franchise");
        alert(x.getElementsByTagName("state")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);          

         </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alert statement is wrong. `x` has no method `getElementsByTagName`.

You can get the first city using:

```
alert(x[0].attributes[0].nodeValue); // shows Scottsdale
```

The second one is:

```
alert(x[1].attributes[0].nodeValue); // shows Arcadia
```

And states:

```
alert(x[0].attributes[1].nodeValue);  // AZ
alert(x[1].attributes[1].nodeValue);  // CA
```