# Javascript get file path

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file called auction.xml that sits in a folder called data. The javascript that calls it sits in a folder called A2 in another folder called htdocs. How do I call it from htdocs? I have tried ../../data/auction.xml but it doesn't work. I have tried calling it using php on another file in the same folder and that worked. The code I used in php was

```
$url = '../../data/customers.xml';
```

which was then put into

```
if(filesize($url)>0)
```

This is what I am trying to call in javascript

```
var url = "../../data/auction.xml";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
```

However, the second one doesn't work.

Current function

```
var url = "getAuction.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
        var str;
        var i;
        str=("<p>Category : <select onchange=\"reveal(this)\" name=category>");
        var categoryList= []; //Array contains the distinct values
        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product");
        var cy=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Category");
        if(x.length>0)
        {
            for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
                var category=cy[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var currentOption ="<option value=" + category + ">" + category  + "</option>";
                //Verify is category has already be added
                if(!contains(categoryList,category))
                {
                    categoryList.push(category);
                    str += currentOption;
                }
            }   
            str+="<option id=\"others\" value=\"Others\">Others</option>";
        }
        else
        str+="<option id=\"others\" value=\"Others\">Others</option>";
        str+=("</select></p>");
        document.getElementById('category').innerHTML=str;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url ,false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ../../data/auction.xml

is not an url, so you can't reach it via a httpRequest. You have to call with javascript a .php - page that gets the Xml for you.
PHP has the Benefit that it's executed on the Server, you can reach all Local Files on it.
Javascript operates on your client in the Browser.

```
Javascript:
var url = "getAuction.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
       var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
       console.log(xmlDoc);
       //do smoething with xmlDoc

    }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url ,false);
 xmlhttp.send();

getAuction.php:
echo file_get_contents("../../data/auction.xml"); //or whatever you want to do with the xml
```

The php file in this example needs to be in the same directory as the javascript.

> XmlHttpRequests are Asynchronous. so you need to define a Callback when th Request is ready like :

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
       var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
       console.log(xmlDoc);
       //do smoething with xmlDoc

    }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","auction.xml",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

from SO [Exception xml.getElementsByTagName is not a function, when trying to parse an xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416958/exception-xml-getelementsbytagname-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-parse-an-xm):

> Your alert statement is wrong. xmlDoc has no method getElementsByTagName.
>
> You can get the first city using: xmlDoc [0].getElementsByTagName()

Comment: I've tried to do it like that, however none of my data loaded. I've edited the code to add my function in the question. Could you see how I could change it?

Comment: But if my getAuction file is in the same directory as the xml file, won't the javascript not be able to detect it? Is that how I pass the information to the javascript?

Comment: if the xml is in the same directory as the javascript, its perfectly fine to call the xml direct

Comment: Yeah but I require it to be in the data folder. Is it possible to use an absolute path?

Comment: edited the first code-block. in the .php you can use whatever path you want

Comment: I've edited my answer. However its saying that getElementsByTagName isn't a function. Sorry to trouble you. I have difficulty understanding this.

Comment: try console.log(xmlDoc); and have a look if it's valid xml

Comment: Yup it is. It shows the xml document in the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416958/exception-xml-getelementsbytagname-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-parse-an-xm this is your answer

Comment: That shows it if it has an attribute though. My first tag which is product is getting the error. That is the root node.

Comment: Maybe you will need to open another question about your xml - getelementsbytagname problem, because this is the point i c'ant help you anymore

Answer (score 0):

In php in script

```
url:"<?php echo site_url('controller/function_name');?>",
```

Comment: Where do I put this? What is the controller/function_name?